# Undefined control sequence \pdfcompresslevel

Tags: errors

I'm trying to run a TeX doc based on a template (the template is apparently fine since it's running by other colleges).  The setting file is as follow:

```
   %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Einstellungen
% (gelten nur in Zusammenarbeit mit pdflatex)
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[
  pagesize,                                            % flexible Auswahl des Papierformats
  a4paper,                                               % DIN A4
  oneside,                                             % einseitiger Druck
  BCOR=5mm,                                              % Bindungskorrektur
  headsepline,                                         % Strich unter der Kopfzeile
  12pt,                                                % 12pt Schriftgr��e
    parskip=half,                                         % Europ�ischer Satz: Abstand zwischen Abs�tzen
    abstracton,                                                                                  % Spezielle Formatierung, die erlaubt, dass die
                                                                                                             % Zusammenfassung vor dem Inhaltsverzeichnis steht
    %draft,                                                                                          % Es handelt sich um eine Vorabversion
    final,                                                                                           % Es handelt sich um die endg�ltige Version
    listof = totoc,                                                                                  % Tabellen- und Abbildungsverzeichnis im                                                                                                                                % Inhaltsverzeichnis
    index = totoc,                                                                                       % Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis
  bibliography = totoc,                                            % Literaturverzeichnis im Inhaltsverzeichnis
]{scrreprt}                                            % KOMA-Scriptklasse Report

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}                    % deutsche Trennmuster
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                               % EC-Schriften, Trennstellen nach Umlauten
%\usepackage[latin1]%{inputenc}                          % direkte Umlauteingabe (� statt "a)
                                                       % latin1/latin9 f�r unixoide Systeme
                                                       % (latin1 ist auch unter Win verwendbar)
                                                       % ansinew f�r Windows
                                                       % applemac Macs
                                                       % cp850 OS/2

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}                                                           % Schriften Paket
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}                                                      % Wichtig f�r Abstandsformatierung

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{cmbright}                                  % serifenlose Schrift als Standard
                                                       % + alle f�r TeX ben�tigten mathematischen
                                                       %   Schriften einschlie�lich der AMS-Symbole
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}                        % skalierte Helvetica als \sfdefault
\usepackage{courier}                                   % Courier als \ttdefault

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}                        % Anpassung der Kopf- und Fu�zeilen
\usepackage{xspace}                                    % Korrekter Leerraum nach Befehlsdefinitionen
\usepackage{setspace}                                                                    % Dieses Package brauchen wir f�r den
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
                                                                                                             % anderthalbzeiligen Abstand.
\usepackage{natbib}                                    % Neuimplementierung des \cite-Kommandos
\usepackage{bibgerm}                                                       % Deutsche Bezeichnungen
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}                         % placing boxes at absolute positions
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}                           % include pages of external PDF documents
\usepackage{tabularx}                                  % Spaltenbreite bis zur Seitenbreite dehnen
\usepackage{makeidx}                                                    % Paket zur Erstellung eines Stichwortverzeichnisses
\makeindex                                                                                       % Automatische Erstellung des Stichwortverzeichnis
\usepackage[intoc,
                        german,
                        prefix]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \usepackage{graphicx}                                 % Zur Einbindung von PDF-Bildern
 \usepackage[colorlinks,                                                             % Einstellen und Laden des Hyperref-Pakets
    pdftex,
    bookmarks,
    bookmarksopen=false,
    bookmarksnumbered,
    citecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linktocpage,
  pdfstartview=Fit,                                  % startet mit Ganzseitenanzeige
    pdfsubject={Multiagentensystemgestätzte Clusteranalyse},
    pdftitle={TESting Stuff},
    pdfauthor={Bköäü Jensen, http://www.mirou.de}]{hyperref}
 \pdfcompresslevel=9

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Inhaltsverzeichnis und Abschnittnummerierung
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}   % Ich habe recht kurze Kapitel. Die sollen nicht durchnummeriert sein.
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Abbildungsverzeichnis
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Kopf- und Fu�zeilen
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadings
\clearscrplain
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ihead{\headmark}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Anpassung der Parameter, die TeX bei der Berechnung der Zeilenumbr�che verwendet:
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\tolerance 1414
\hbadness 1414
\emergencystretch 1.5em
\hfuzz 0.3pt
\widowpenalty=10000
\vfuzz \hfuzz
\raggedbottom
```

In the rest of the template, there is no configurations, so I guess the problem is definitely here. The error message I get is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.

\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.79  \pdfcompresslevel
                       =9
?
```

And I really don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Afaik the problem must be in the `enstellungen` folder files (which I do not have, of course). Removing those two inputs it works fine for me

Comment: Off-topic: This is a very bad template (using KOMA and manipulating TeX primitives). Do you really need all that stuff?

Comment: `\pdfcompresslevel` is a pdftex primitive. so you are presumably using a different tex engine. luatex, perhaps?

Comment: @Moriambar that's the file in Einstellung ?

Comment: @Texnician oh yes I need it

Comment: David I'm not well I'n using pdfLatex+Makeindex+Bibtex

Comment: What TeX distribution are you on?

Comment: If you want to write a scientific report, i have [another template in mind](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports).

Comment: please remove  lines such as `\input{einstellungen/neuebefehle.sty}`  so that other people can run the example, then show the full log.  You could of course simply delete the `\pdfcompresslevel` line as it is the default value anyway but it should work.

Comment: That *template* is really bad. Packages that are obsolete for years, options nobody needs anymore. Other weird stuff. My advice: Don't use this template.

Comment: @David I've done that in the folder Einstellung there only 1 file now !